# Surface charge density relation with the radius of curvature at the surface of a conductor

Tags: electrostatics, charge, curvature, conductors

In a text book it was given that the surface charge density of a conductor at a particular region on its surface is inversely proportional to the radius of curvature at that region. I didn't understand it. I'd like to see a proof for that can anyone please post the proof.

Comment: This question seems to be very interesting, I do not understand why it is closed!

Answer (score 6):

The equation for electrostatic potential for point charge is $V = kQ/r$

Now assume an object made up of two charged conducting spherical shells one of radius $R$ and one of radius $r$ ($R > r$)touching each other externally.{ The potential for any shell of radius $r$ having charge $q$ at its surface is same as potential for a point charge $q$ at distance $r$.}

Now for the small sphere since $r$ is less charge on its surface has to be more in order to maintain a constant potential over the entire surface.

> $ kQ_{small}/r = kQ_{big}/R$
>          charge density = Q/A.
>          $Q_{small}/Q_{big} = r/R$
>          $(Q_{small}/{4\pi r^2}) / (Q_{big}/4\pi R^2) = (r/{4 \pi r^2}) / (R/{4 \pi R^2})$
>          ${(Q/A)}_{small}/{(Q/A)}_{big} = R/r$

Therefore the charge density at sharp edges of any charged surface provided the surface is conducting is more than the rest of the surface