# Charge density on uneven outer surface of a metallic conductor

Tags: electrostatics

It is said that the charge distribution on the outer surface of a metallic conductor is inversely proportional to the local radius of curvature. Most explanations involve taking imaginary spheres at any 2 points (1 and 2) with different local radii of curvature (r1 and r2 say). Then by claiming that the surface of the conductor is an equipotential surface ,the potentials(V1 and V2) at 1 and 2 are calculated individually by considering the charge at sphere 1 **only** for V1 and charge at sphere 2 **only** for V2.

But why don't we also consider the potentials due to the other points on the metallic surface at 1 and 2 ? A rigorous proof would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a reference to such a proof that you explain is insufficient?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93649/surface-charge-density-relation-with-the-radius-of-curvature-at-the-surface-of-a

Comment: Why do you think the argument doesn't apply to all points on the surface. A general point is picked as a reference, and then we look at some other general point on the surface. Therefore it should be true anywhere.

Comment: My question is why the charges on other points on the surface apart from the point contained in the imaginary sphere do not affect the potential ?

Comment: Conductors are equipotentials. The charge distribution will always adjust so that this is the case. The proof you link to already considers the effect all charges have on the potential by using this fact.

Comment: In the proof , it is written that kQ_big/R = kQ_small/r  . If the effect of all charges was considered then wouldn't the expression look something like 
( kQ_big/R + kQ_small/d ) where d is the distance between the centre of the smaller sphere and the point on the bigger sphere?

Comment: Each side of the equation is the potential at the surface of that sphere. They are set to be equal because it is a conductor. It doesn't matter how far apart these spheres are. You have two charged spheres each with some potential at their surface. Since they belong to the same conductor they must have the same potential.

Comment: Why is the potential at the surface of the sphere only dependent on the charge on the sphere and not any other surrounding charge ?

Comment: It's not. But the charge on the surface of the sphere should mostly determine it's potential I suppose.

Comment: Is there any source/theorem/law supporting your claim that the charge on the sphere mostly determines the potential ? If it exists I would love to refer it and update my knowledge.

Comment: It's an approximation.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for this approximation. Is there any calculus kind of 
explanation?

Comment: No. It's like how we say friction is equal to $\,mu N$. It's a simplified situation that is generally true. You could contrive some weird conductor where all of this is not true, but for many situations this should be fine.

Comment: I have seen situations where a conductor is constructed by joining two spheres of unequal radii and a charge placed on one of the spheres is allowed to redistribute between the two. This situation also gives the result that the charge density on the two spheres is inversely proportional to the radii of curvature but on the assumption that the two spheres are very far apart. I would like know if there is some connection between the two situations - a)infinitely far apart conductors and b) continuous conductors as the result is the same ?

Comment: Thank you for your help until now.