# Relation between radius of curvature and charge density

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, conductors

As we know in electrostatics, a metallic surface is equipotential and any charge residing on it miraculously enough distributes itself such that the conductor becomes equipotential. The surface charge density somewhat varies linearly with the radius of curvature.

How do we find an exact (or approximate) relation between radius of curvature and the local charge density  for a metallic surface?

Comment: Are you asking how would it vary if you had the same amount of charge over varying radius? Do you know what the definition of charge density is and what the surface area of a sphere is?

Comment: I assume the metal piece is placed into a uniform e-field. The final e-field is more complex, but the potential is the everywhere in the conductor because if it weren't, the mobile charges would move to equalize it. Like the water level in a quiescent lake.

Comment: This is not about placing a sphere in an electric field at all.

Comment: Where the word "sphere" is coming from? See the definition of radius of curvature first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Surface charge density relation with the radius of curvature at the surface of a conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93649/surface-charge-density-relation-with-the-radius-of-curvature-at-the-surface-of-a)

Answer (score 2):

The surface density of charges depends on the shape of the whole surface, not only the local curvature. References:

- "The lightning-rod fallacy",  R. H. Price & R. J. Crowley, 1985; American Journal of Physics, 53, 843;
- "Of lightning rods, charged conductors, curvature, and things", I. M. Benn & S. T. Shanahan, 1991; AJP, 59, 658.