Surface charge density on conductor is proportional to $1/r$
I was reading this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93654 which states that for a conducting surface,
$$\sigma=c*(1/r)$$
where r is the so called "radius of curvature at that point"
My question is since a surface has 2 perpendicular principal curvatures $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$, what kind of curvature are we taking here? Is it the gaussian curvature or the mean curvature or a totally different thing? Like if two points on the same surface have the same gaussian curvature/mean curvature/something else will they have the same surface charge density?

Arham Zahid’s answer is wrong and there is quite a lot of literature on the topic. A typical counterexample is the case of an ellipsoid. The surface charge density is (geometrically, it is the support function):
$$
\sigma\propto \frac1{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+ \frac{y^2}{b^4}+ \frac{z^2}{c^4}}}
$$
while gaussian curvature is:
$$
K\propto\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+ \frac{y^2}{b^4}+ \frac{z^2}{c^4}}^4}
$$
and the mean curvature is:
$$
H\propto \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2-b^2-c^2}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^4}+ \frac{y^2}{b^4}+ \frac{z^2}{c^4}}^3}
$$
so at best what you can claim is that:
$$
\sigma\propto K^{1/4}
$$
It holds for many surfaces, but it is not true for all of them.
Perhaps Arham Zahid mistook $\sigma$ the surface charge with $\frac{dE}{dn}$ the normal derivative of the electric field. In the latter case, yes you do have:
$$
\frac{dE}{dn}\propto H
$$
In general, surface charge density is not local, it depends on the global geometry of the conductor. Therefore you will not find a general formula relating it to local quantities such as curvature etc. except for special classes of surfaces.
You can find an introductory review of the topic in On the dependence of charge density on surface curvature of an isolated conductor by Kolahal Bhattacharya (free arxiv version).
